# If and for loop logic in c#, if error how to skip the next step

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop

[image]

I have more than 2 strings one is email and one is group, if both are valid then I should execute push to server(). I am comparing the string to find whether it is email or string, that is done before the for()loop.

In this logic I want to run the sendto push server code only when both the conditions are succesful, The input will be both email and group. If email is correct and if group is correct only then the send to push server should be executed. If any one is wrong it should not be executed. I can run the send to push server only I cant do it once for email and once for group thats why I have it after executing both email and group. If there is any error in any one group or email then I should not execute the send to push server I have to skip it. how can I do that

Comment: Your link is broken. Consider pasting the code as text.

Comment: Can't you rewrite the image into actual code as text?

Comment: @Mark I transferred your image to a different host and embedded it.

Comment: I have more than 2 strings one is email and one is group, if both are valid then I should execute push to server(). I am comparing the string to find whether it is email or string, that is done before the for()loop.

Comment: The pseudo-code you have posted looks sufficient. Are you just looking for the C# syntax equivalent, or something else? I'm afraid it's not very obvious what kind of answer you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for()
{
    if(!email)
    {
        Alert();
    }
    else
    {
        EnterUserDetailsInTable();
    }

    if(!group)
    {
        Alert();
    }
    else
    {
        EnterGroupDetailsInTable();
    }

    if(email && group)
    {
        PushToServer();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but I really don't understand the need of the for... are you using a for if structure just to take two parameters?? (this is for OP)

Comment: @gbianchi - I agree, I simply copied it from the original code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices:

```
for(var something in stuff)
{
    if(something.condition)
    {
        // send to server
    }
}
```

Inversing the condition to avoid nesting:

```
for(var something in stuff)
{
    if(!something.condition) continue;

    // send to server
}
```

Using LINQ to restrict your results ahead of time:

```
for(var something in stuff.Where(s => s.condition))
{
    // send to server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
forloop
{
    if ((condition1) && (condition2))
    {
       //sendtoserver
    }
}
```

That's speudo-code because quite frankly I'm taking a guess here and I don't fully understand what you're asking... I *think* this is it though...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand you correctly, but if you’re asking how to execute the last part only if both “Correct”’s were done: add a

```
    bool flagEmail = false;
    bool flagGroup = false;
```

Before your code.
And after every “Enter...” add:

```
flag...=true;
```

and in the end:

```
    if(flagEmail && flagGroup) ...//Send to push server.
```

Comment: I want to check the if(flagEmail && flagGroup) after the for loop is completely over. If I update the flagemail inside the if loop I am not able to access it outside the for loop

Comment: @Mark Incorrect.  that’s why I wrote to declare the bool’s _before_ your code. You _will_ then be able to access them outside the loop.